# Подмена(Mock) base-метода

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mocking, nsubstitute

Есть код:

```
public override bool Method()
{
    bool result = false;

    if (!(result = base.Method()))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else { /*...*/ }
}
```

Код базового метода:

```
public virtual bool Method()
{
    return true;
}
```

То есть получается что `base.Method()` всегда возвращает `true` и в этот `if` нету как зайти..

**Вопрос:** Как можно его подменить, желательно средствами `.NET` или `NSubstitute`, что бы получилось что то вроде:

```
target.Method().Base.Returns(false);
```

Comment: А в чем вообще смысл вашего `if`, если базовый метод всегда возвращает `true`?

Comment: @andreycha, это хороший вопрос, но не мне.. не я писал этот класс.. Задача покрыть тестами.. В целом это не критично, покрыть на 100%, но для себя стало интересно можно ли так сделать.

Comment: Так а вы смотрите чуть дальше задачи. В чем смысл покрытия участка кода, который никогда не выполняется? Такой участок кода надо просто удалить. По теме: NSubstitute так не умеет, за остальные фреймворки не скажу, давно с ними работал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В .NET можно подменить вызов следующих вещей:

- виртуального метода - при вызове через ссылку на объект
- реализации метода интерфейса - при вызове через ссылку на интерфейс
- чего угодно у класса-наследника `MarshalByRefObject`

Первые два пункта делаются генерацией прокси-наследников. Третий - средствами ремоутинга (т.е. тоже практически через генерацию прокси).

Все остальные вызовы в .NET - это вписанные в IL вызовы конкретных методов. Их нельзя подменить средствами .NET (и средствами моков, соответственно).

Такое можно сделать фреймворками, которые переписывают IL (статически, перед запуском тестов, или привешиваясь к приложению как профайлер).

Например, [Microsoft Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) точно может переписать результат вызова в вашем примере `Class1.Method()`. Достаточно добавить Fake Assembly из контекстного меню в References у тестов, и переписать тест примерно так:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Class2 class2instance = new Class2();
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ClassLibrary1.Fakes.ShimClass1.AllInstances.Method = (c1) => false;

        var result = class2instance.Method();
    }
}
```

Но у него есть некоторые ограничения - например, запуск тестов именно через VSTest Execution Engine.

Есть ли аналогичные фреймворки не от MS - не уверен.

Comment: Плюсанул и переставил метку. Завтра сможете отдать последние голоса за синонимизацию юнит-тестов.